# How was Potassium used to estimate the effect of backgrounds in the Homestake experiment?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, neutrinos

I'm trying to understand some of the details of the Homestake experiment, which attempted to measure the rate of neutrino production by the sun. In particular, I'm interested in how Davis et. al. accounted for backgrounds coming from other neutrino sources. In his original paper, as well as in [this](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/0146641094900043?token=176DF4090277DC84716DE3E728E72991009A8068CD8208725669D2954151E0CD91A8ECFB9B4FBC3F0B4C3383584463C4&originRegion=us-east-1&originCreation=20220518233722) summary, it seems as though Davis is implying that potassium can be converted to Argon via interaction with muons from cosmic rays (page 22 in the linked paper). The rate of this reaction underground can then be studied to understand the rate at which cosmic rays travel through the ground, which can then be used to determine the effect of cosmic rays on other experiments. How does this reaction between muons and Potassium work though? In the paper, Davis writes the reaction as below in the screenshot: [image: Reaction] I don't understand this notation, however. Can someone explain in more detail how this reaction works? Additionally, what I have recounted above is my current understanding of the procedure to account for error. If anything I have said is wrong, I welcome corrections.

Comment: A(B,C)D is shorthand for A+B -> C+D